# Pointing multiple domain names at same place

Tags: dns, seo

I have a website ranking well in Google, my current website has dashes in and looks like so...

```
this-is-mine.com
```

Ive just also bought

```
thisismine.com
```

I'd like to point the latter to my first site, but I dont want it to be classed as duplicate content.

I'm unsure if I just do this through 123-reg but will this affect my Google rankings, or is there a correct way of doing this without penalising myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link below, my thoughts are confirmed.

A 301 is fine as it forwards everything including page rank to the "new" site. In your case this-is-mine.com.

A 302 could/would be a problem for SEO.

http://seo-hacker.com/301-302-redirect-affect-seo/

Comment: I'm assuming you've bought the new domain so that nobody tries to operate under the same name. Or people are mistyping your URL. Either way, for the small amount a domain costs, worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

If your current website is ranking well then don't disturb it. There is no benefits in pointing multiple domains on one website. You can also make a single page website on the new domain and optimize it for Google and link with your old one.

If you still want to do this then do a 301 redirect but make sure that the domain is new and has no spammy back links pointing to it.